# @protocol with integers

Tags: objective-c, delegates, int, protocols

I am trying to make a protocol for a detail view for a tableView. The detail view has a question and then an answer. If I get the answer correct, it will set an integer to *increase*  by 1 in a protocol method.

I am new to protocols and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

## Code

### DetailViewController.h

#### Where the protocol is made

```
#import "Question.h"

@protocol DetailQuestionViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:(int)questionNumberChanged;
@end

@interface DetailQuestionViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Question *selectedQuestion;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *answerField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *correctLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <DetailQuestionViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (assign, nonatomic) int questionsCorrect;
```

### DetailViewController.m

```
@implementation DetailQuestionViewController

@synthesize questionLabel;
@synthesize answerField;
@synthesize correctLabel;
@synthesize selectedQuestion;
@synthesize questionsCorrect;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Sets the questionLabel to the question we put in the array
    self.questionLabel.text = [selectedQuestion questionName]; 

    // Sets the navigation title to the rowName we put in the array
    self.navigationItem.title = [selectedQuestion questionRowName]; 

   NSLog(@"The question's answer for the question you selected is %@", [selectedQuestion questionAnswer]);


}

- (IBAction)checkAnswer:(UITextField *)sender
{

    if ([[selectedQuestion questionAnswer] caseInsensitiveCompare:answerField.text] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        // Show the  correct label
        [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
        correctLabel.text = @"Correct!";
        correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        *questionsCorrect = 1;
        NSLog(@"questionsCorrect int is %d", questionsCorrect);
        [self.delegate questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:questionsCorrect];*

    }
        else
        {
            // Show the incorrect label
            [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
            correctLabel.text = @"Incorrect";
            correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        }

        // Erase the text in the answerField
        answerField.text = @"";
}
```

### ScoreViewController.h

#### Now here is my ScoreView which will be acsessing the delegate

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailQuestionViewController.h"

@interface ScoreViewController : UIViewController *<DetailQuestionViewControllerDelegate>*


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

- (IBAction)resetButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
-(void)checkScore;

@end
```

### ScoreViewController.m

```
#import "ScoreViewController.h"
#import "DetailQuestionViewController.h"

@interface ScoreViewController ()

@end

@implementation ScoreViewController
@synthesize scoreLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    *DetailQuestionViewController *dqvc = [[DetailQuestionViewController alloc] init];
    dqvc.delegate = self;*

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self checkScore];

}

-(void)checkScore
{

}

- (IBAction)resetButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{

}

#pragma mark - DetailQuestionViewControllerDelegate -
*-(void)questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:(int)questionNumberChanged*
{
    //set the textlabel text value to the number of questions correct
    NSLog(@"questionsNumberChanged is %i", questionNumberChanged);
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You answered %d questions correctly",questionNumberChanged];
}

@end
```

The label is never updating for some reason.

Sorry for making the question so long, tried to be very specific.

Comment: Downvoting, huh? Happy New Year then :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing somewhat here as you talk about increasing a value in a protocol method, yet you don't have a single `+` or `++` anywhere... You also have quite a few `*`'s sprinkled in strange places in your sample code, it is unclear whether these are typos, intended as emphasis, or intended to be pointer indirection.

So you have a property `questionsCorrect` in your `DetailQuestionViewController` class so let's assume this is the class you expect to own the counter (we'll skip that this is a view and not a model class...). If this is the idea then lines:

```
    *questionsCorrect = 1;
    NSLog(@"questionsCorrect int is %d", questionsCorrect);
    [self.delegate questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:questionsCorrect];*
```

should be:

```
    self.questionsCorrect++;  // increment the counter
    NSLog(@"questionsCorrect int is %d", self.questionsCorrect);
    [self.delegate questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:self.questionsCorrect];
```

(you can also declare the instance variable `questionsCorrect` yourself and drop the use of `self.` above - whichever you prefer)

Now just go through and remove the other cases of extra `*`'s if they are in your code as well as the sample above and you'll be a bit closer to your goal.

If alternatively you wish `ScoreViewController` to own the counter then you need to declare it there and provide a method to increment and display it.

HTH

Comment: Sorry. The stars were ment to be emphasis. Don't know why it didn't work in the question creation. I did what you said to do with my code, but the label still says I only got 1 question correct, not 2 or 3 etc...

Comment: Did that too. Still, nope.

Comment: @Yuval Marcus Edit your question and fix remove the extra "*" characters. Check the statements: `*-(void)questionsCorrectHasChangedTo:(int)questionNumberChanged*` and `*DetailQuestionViewController *dqvc = [[DetailQuestionViewController alloc] init];
    dqvc.delegate = self;*` With the extra "*"s it is hard to trust the code.

Comment: @YuvalMarcus - stars don't work for emphasis in code fragments. If you now have changed your code to increment `questionsCorrect`, the value stays at 1 on the label, and you get multiple `NSLog` lines stating the value is 1 then that suggests you have multiple `DetailQuestionViewController` instances each with its own counter - each one starts at zero and is incremented once. If this is the case you need to have a *shared* counter, one possibility is to include it in your `ScoreViewController` class as per the last para above.